# How to log a warning if a template helper is not found?

Tags: meteor

Is there a way to log to the console if a template helper is not found. Currently nothing is printed, it would be helpful for debugging if a warning is printed to the console.

For example if using a helper like {{{myLocale}}}, and it is not found, it would print to the console 'Helper "myLocale" not found..' etc etc.

Comment: As long as it is in the correct template it should find it.  I would think the danger would lie in returning a null or invalid value.

Comment: doesn't it already? hmm interesting :)

Comment: @MarkUretsky I think it does so for templates (`{{>`/`{{#`), but not helpers.

Comment: @Gaelan well so it's still possible to do `{{#if value}}available{{else}}not found value!!!{{/if}}`